# Conditional formatting with if formula

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

On Google Spreadsheet, I want cell `D88` to change background color depending on the value in `E88`. In my head this should work like this (imagine it's a conditional formatting window):

> =if(E88="yes") then **format background** and chose orange for **range** D88

Also, `D88` content is yes, obviously. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Because the formatting is *Conditional* you should not normally need an IF statement in the formula. Just:

```
=E88="yes"
```

should be sufficient, regardless of any text in D88.